# Retrieve match from list of strings and add as column in dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains columns `text` and `user`.

| user | text |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | I love bananas |
| Dick | I love apples |
| Harry | I love apples and bananas |

I want to find rows of `text` which contain a list of `fruits`. For
each matched string, a new row is added to new columns `fruits` and `fruits_with_colors`. The expected output is below:

| user | text | fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | I love bananas | bananas |
| Dick | I love apples | apples |
| Harry | I love apples and bananas | apples |
| Harry | I love apples and bananas | bananas |

I'm having some trouble thinking about how to do this. I was doing the following using pandas:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'bananas']

df_with_matches = df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(fruits))]
```

but am returning the error `sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: Is the second table the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for that, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.findall` to extract fruits into a list and then `explode` it:

```
df.assign(fruits = df.text.str.findall('|'.join(fruits))).explode('fruits')

    user                        text   fruits
0    Tom              I love bananas  bananas
1   Dick               I love apples   apples
2  Harry   I love apples and bananas   apples
2  Harry   I love apples and bananas  bananas
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 This looks like a good solution; for me its returning the error `sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: It's because your `fruits` list has an inner list and `join` throws the error.

Comment: A further further question about this solution. It will also match parts of strings in the list, not full words  e.g. `ba`. Do I need to specifiy `r'\bbananas\b'` in the list, or is there a way to include regex in the search?

Comment: If you need a full match, you can use `'\\b' + '\\b|\\b'.join(fruits) + '\\b'` to create the pattern